# try-with-resources- Not allowed for source level below 7 but i need it to work at 6

Tags: java, bufferedreader

How can I modfy this to work on Java 6?

> Resource specification not allowed here for source level below 1.7
>
> The type BufferedReader is not visible

---

```
public static void findFrequency() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader ins = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"))) {
        int r;
        while ((r = ins.read()) != -1) {
            text=text+String.valueOf((char)r);
            freq[r]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use try-with-resources.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resource specification not allowed error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352251/resource-specification-not-allowed-error)

Comment: try-with-resources is Java 7+, it won't work with Java 6

Comment: right but dont have time. Need to upload couldnt, went crazy for it i wrote it this way but couldnt change it always gave an error.

Answer (score 1):

To work with earlier versions of Java (without [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)), make a small change...

```
BufferedReader ins = null;
try { 
  ins = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
  // As before...
} finally {
  if (ins != null) {
    try {
      ins.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What about the `finally` block containing the call to `close()`?

Comment: Thank you but it now says that , insert finnaly to complete try statement.

Comment: @user3447855 Edited to fix that. Sorry.